# How to custom UITableViewCell. When I push the UITableViewCell, text area will open below the cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

[Environment]
iOS 7.0 or more than
XCode 6.0.1

I searched Japanese and English information.
But, I couldn't get information about it in Objective-C.
I would like to custom UITableViewCell. When I push the UITableViewCell,
text area will open below the cell (reference:picture).
How can I use make this work or is there any github library ?
I searched the keyword about "accordion". 
But it is not what I imagined.

sincerely yours,[image]

Comment: Is your tableview dynamic prototypes or static?

Comment: Well, you need to dynamically change the height of the cell, then reload it.

Comment: >>SASmith  I want to make it with dynamic.

Comment: >>Hot Licks      Thank you so much !!   I could get same answer in Japanese stackoverflow. I will do it with your answer :)